# Pre Render before route or ng-view AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to fetch user details before angularjs starts using controllers. I'm okay with it hooking up services and factories but nothing with the view. I'd like a big white screen or a loading screen and then once the user detail comes back from service continue loading the screen. Like a pre fetch up front. AngularJS doesn't seem to allow this, it wants to do everything immediately. How can I prerun scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `resolve` clause in the route declaration.